# Can I pull up a 5V logic line to 12V without damaging anything?

Tags: microcontroller, level-shifting, pullup

What happens if I pull a 5V logic line (from a µC via a [74HCT245 level shifter](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/sn74lvc245a.pdf)) up to 12V with a, say, 10KΩ resistor? Is this going to damage anything?

My goal is to have the logic line at the same potential as the 12V rail when the µC and level shifter are not powered, but to "obey" the 0V and 5V logic level output of the level shifter when they are.

Comment: 1) include a schematic of what you want to do 2) to go from 5 V to 12 V you will probably need an open drain output designed for doing this, normal outputs will **always** include an ESD diode between the output and the supply of the chip, if the chip runs on 5 V this diode prevents the output going above 5.7 V due to this ESD diode. 3) a 10 k resistor is high enough to prevent a damaging current to flow but the real issue is the ESD protection preventing the any pin going above 5.7 V.

Comment: A pullup resistor such as described will power the CMOS chip through its output pin, so the 'not powered' phrase is only wishful thinking.

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: when you say "pull up to" do you mean conncet a 10K resistor between the microcontroller and a 12V signal?

Comment: The 74HCT245 is not a 'level shifter' but a transceiver. If you must do this, you need to use a buffer specifically designed for the job so that the 5V circuitry is isolated from the 12V supply  - as an example, the ULN2003A power driver has the desired characteristics.

Comment: Ok, ok, it’s a question coming from a position of ignorance (are there any others?) but it’s honest. And there is a good, well-upvoted answer. Why the downvotes?

Comment: 12 volts on any pin of the 74HCT245 buffer will blow it. It is a 5 volt only device. It is meant as a data bus buffer-no more.

Comment: @Sparky256 I think that's the crux of it. The ground of the 74HCT245 will still be connected, so by pulling up that line I'm putting 12V across the chip, which is obviously—even to me—a Bad Idea.

Answer (score 8):

For most normal digital inputs, you will forward bias the protection diode to Vdd.  What happens after that depends on how the specific chip was designed and the external circuitry.  Some possibilities are:

The 5 V power supply won't let the the voltage go much above 5 V.  Either the 12 V source will have to drop, or the protection diode burns out.

The 5 V supply rises to 12 V minus the diode drop.  This could blow out everything connected to the 5 V supply.

The protection diode and 5 V supply are beefy enough so that the thing trying to drive 12 V has to source too much current, and it burns out.

If power and ground of the micro are floating, then all the I/O pins will now also float to 12 V or a bit below.  That could be bad for anything connected to the I/O pins.

The micro becomes powered up and starts doing unexpected things, due to its max power voltage spec being violated.

In short, when you violate any parameter in a datasheet, the manufacturer's promise of the remaining specs are null and void.  The chip could catch fire, vanish into a cloud of greasy black smoke, or just sit there appearing to take it, but subtely do erroneous things that aren't immediately obvious.  All around, this is a **bad idea**.

Comment: that 10K resistor is going to reduce most of those bad effects.

Comment: @Jasen: I don't agree. I'd consider 10k a pull up, not even a weak one. Assume another 10k pullup in an attached microcontroller – now you've got 10V with a 20 kΩ source impedance frying your 5V electronics. Think about this: even without frying, if your microcontroller draws a something like 250µA from the involuntary supply, when trying to turn on, you'd end up with 10V – 250µA · 20kΩ = 5V on the supply line, allowing the microcontroller to *nearly* boot, but then fail when drawing a little more current, reset, start again, rinse, repeat. That is potentially *extremely* harmful, as it might

Comment: not only do whatever to its peripheral state, but also, never reach a state where things like temperature control fully works and simply slowly burn.

Comment: and things will usually be much much worse – as Olin said, if you apply a pin voltage >> Vin, then you conduct current through protection diodes, which have very low resistance for forward voltages in the range of 5 to 10V! This **will** definitely happen, because you must have capacitors on the supply lines. So you *rapidly* charge these capacitors, until their voltage is close enough to 10V to stop the protection diode from working, if it hasn't gone into a permanently failed state at that point. Great, now you've got an array of  9V charged capacitors on your 5V supply. These can supply an

Comment: arbitrary (nearly arbitrary) high current for a short time. I don't know which high-robustness microcontrollers you use, but seriously, who goes and says "hey, this is a data line, let's use it with twice it's maximum voltage, even with Vin floating or even pulled low (from a transient perspective, caps are shorts)" must be stopped right there and be told: No, your flimsy 10kΩ resistors do not provide sufficient protection.

Comment: a 7805 acts a lot like a zener when unpowered - that can stop lots of damage

Comment: where are you gettiting this 20K from?

Comment: papragraph 2 false.  most likely you drop 7V across the 10K resistor.  paragraph 3 false (assuming there's a power LED) papragraph 4 false (unless 0.7mA burns it out),  3 out of 5 is "most"

Comment: 20 kΩ = 10kΩ form your comment, plus the "assume another 10 kΩ pullup". You started inventing a power LED and a 7805, which are nowhere to be found in OP's question; you can't assume either. 7V across a 10kΩ would require 700µA, and I explicitly said I was modelling with less, because on early reset, a microcontroller doesn't draw that much. And yes, 700 µA is a burn out current for micro- to nanometer wide semiconductor elements.

Comment: 20K why bother. 10K + diode has lower resistance.

Comment: @Jasen: My answer is for the general case of raising a I/O well above Vdd.  It's not clear at all that the OP will put a 10 kOhm resistor in series.  Note the question mark.  He then clarified *"My goal is to have the logic line at the same potential as the 12V rail"*.